# How to store string replacement as object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have the following

```
astring.replace(/(someregex/g, "replacementstring.$1")
```

I'd like to store it as some sort of object, so I can call it in the future. The obvious solution is to store it as two variables `someregex` and `replacementstring` and call it in the future as `astring.replace(someregex, replacementstring + '.$1')` But that seems really clunky to me.

Is there anyway to store the string replacement in a more concise manner? My current idea is to store `.replace(/someregex/g, "replacementstring.$1")` as a string called `stringreplacement` and use `eval('astring' + stringreplacement)`. But that seems silly.

Comment: Well, for the regex part you could store it as an actual RegExp object.  `var pattern = new RegExp("someregex", "g");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use currying to define a function where some variables are already pre-defined.

For example:

```js
function replace(find, replace) {
  return function (string) {
    return string.replace(find, replace);
  }
}

const replacer = replace(/hello/gi, "G'day");

console.log(replacer('hello fubar'));
```